# How can I update only the proguard in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, proguard, android-proguard

I have older version of the android studio and I am happy from that. I think in newer version of the android studio, the `proguard` has been updated also.

Now, I want to have the updated version of `proguard` in my android studio. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android SDK Manager does not have different proguard feature available as they have like Android support library , Android support reposatory , Google play services and many more but not proguard.

so according to me it is not possible to update only proguard in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You could download a zip distribution of a newer Android release and replace files manually. However this might not work at all because of incompabilities.

I recommend you to update to the latest Version. It has improved a lot since 1.0, but it hasn't changed much (instead added) so you will be able to use it without problems. To use the newer proguard you just have to change one line per gradle script once, which is really no big deal.